# Sum values from specific field of the objects in a list

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Suppose to have a class `Obj`:

```
class Obj {
  int field;
}
```

...and that you have a list of `Obj` instances, i.e. `List<Obj> lst`.

Now, how can I find with streams the sum of the values of the int fields `field` from the objects in list `lst` under a filtering criterion (e.g. for an object `o`, the criterion is `o.field > 10`)?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can do

```
int sum = lst.stream().filter(o -> o.getField() > 10).mapToInt(o -> o.getField()).sum();
```

or (using Method reference)

```
int sum = lst.stream().filter(o -> o.getField() > 10).mapToInt(Obj::getField).sum();
```

Comment: Or `int sum = lst.stream().mapToInt(Obj::getField).filter(n -> n > 10).sum();`

Answer (score 12):

You can also `collect` with an appropriate summing collector like [`Collectors#summingInt(ToIntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

> Returns a `Collector` that produces the sum of a integer-valued function
>   applied to the input elements. If no elements are present, the result
>   is 0.

For example

```
Stream<Obj> filtered = list.stream().filter(o -> o.field > 10);
int sum = filtered.collect(Collectors.summingInt(o -> o.field));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try

```
int sum = list.stream().filter(o->o.field>10).mapToInt(o->o.field).sum();
```

Like explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8 for an `Obj` entity with `field` and getField() method you can use:

```
List<Obj> objs ...

Double sum = objs.stream()
  .filter(Objects::notNull);
  .mapToDouble(Obj::getField)
  .sum();
```

Comment: What does this answer add to the topic? There is no mention of `Indicator` anywhere in the question, and all the answers are already very specific. So unless you can edit your answer to really add something useful to the topic at hand, I suggest you delete it.

Comment: Changed names to help Olivier's abstract thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
int sum = lst.stream().filter(o -> o.field > 10).mapToInt(o -> o.field).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this method: "IntSummaryStatistics"

```
IntSummaryStatistics insum = li.stream().filter(v-> v%2==0).mapToInt(mapper->mapper).summaryStatistics();
```