# How to sum up values of same field from the list of the same object type to just one object

Tags: java, json

Suppose to have a class `Obj`

```
class Obj {
BigDecimal a;
BigDecimal b;
BigDecimal c;
BigDecimal d;
BigDecimal e;
BigDecimal f;
}
```

and that you have a list of a multiple Obj instances with diffrent 'a',...,'f' values i.e. `List<Obj> objList`. For example the JSON response of this object would look like:

```
 {
    "a": 5,
    "b": 6,
    "c": 7,
    "d": 8,
    "e": 9,
    "f": 10,
},
{
    "a": 11,
    "b": 12,
    "c": 13,
    "d": 14,
    "e": 15,
    "f": 16,
},
```

And my question is how can I find in Java with streams how to sum the BigDecimal values from each object in list and return one object with total a, b, c, d, e, f?
Based on the examples i would like to achive the JSON response look like this:

```
{
    "a": 16,
    "b": 18,
    "c": 20,
    "d": 22,
    "e": 24,
    "f": 26,
}
```

I tried with this [Java8: sum values from specific field of the objects in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110853/java8-sum-values-from-specific-field-of-the-objects-in-a-list) solution but it not works for BigDecimals and I dont know how handle it when a class got many field

Answer (score 1):

You Can try something like below, I'm using the same class Obj for keeping the Sum of the fields and looping through only once through the List

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyFirstJavProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Obj> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(new Obj(BigDecimal.ONE,BigDecimal.valueOf(2L),BigDecimal.valueOf(5L)));
        myList.add(new Obj(BigDecimal.ONE,BigDecimal.valueOf(5L),BigDecimal.valueOf(8L)));
        Obj sumOf = new Obj(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal.ZERO);
        myList.stream().forEach(o -> {
            sumOf.a = sumOf.a.add(o.a);
            sumOf.b = sumOf.b.add(o.b);
            sumOf.c = sumOf.c.add(o.c);
        });
        System.out.println(sumOf);


    }
}
class Obj {
    BigDecimal a;
    BigDecimal b;
    BigDecimal c;
    Obj(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b,BigDecimal c){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Obj{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                ", c=" + c +
                '}';
    }
}
```